# How to attach an event on Tkinter Checkbutton in python, to toggle the state

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm attaching an event on CheckButton to change the item's state by left clicking it, and the expected result is state toggle. That means if the checkbutton is selected, then de-select it, if it's de-selected, select it. Below is the code:

```
def onLeftClick(event):
if event.widget.select()==True and event.widget['state']=='normal':
    event.widget.deselect()
elif event.widget.deselect()==True and event.widget['state']=='normal':
    event.widget.select()
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation.

Comment: Why are you binding an event to a checkbutton? It already has bindings that toggle the state of the checkbutton.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know tk, but from context, it looks like you are using `select` and `deselect` to both query the current state of the widget and to set the current state of the widget which seems wrong.

According to http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/checkbutton.html there is a function `toggle` which makes me think

```
def onLeftClick(event):

    if event.widget['state']=='normal':
       event.widget.toggle()
```

will do what you want.